# custom fields not showing before get_header

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, page-template

I am trying to use this code in my WordPress site

```
<?php

    if(get_post_format() == 'video'){   

        function insert_game(){
            get_template_part( 'content', 'video-top' );    
        }

        add_action( 'colormag_after_header', 'insert_game' );
    }
 ?>


<?php get_header(); ?>
```

**and in content-video-top.php is this code**

```
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video', true );
```

The problem is that it doesn't show the custom fields, **but after `get_header()` it works**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at that point, `$post` is not yet defined, you can make sure by [turning debugging on](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Then add this before your `get_post_meta( $post...`:

```
global $post;
```

Or you can replace `$post->ID` with `get_the_ID()`.